# Control appearance of OnOff Switch

Tags: codenameone

I have an OnOffSwitch in my UI.  It has its UUID set to a specific style.

when I modify the colors of this style, the full OnOffSwitch is affected.  How can I make it so the sliding piece has one background color and the area inside the full box has another?  I'd like a green square with a black border sliding over a transparent background with a slightly thicker black border.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make your own OnOffSwitch images, 3 of them:

1. switchOffImage = the off state image (In your case, a slightly thicker black border image)
2. switchOnImage = the on state image (In your case, a green square with a black border)
3. switchMaskImage = A square transparent mask image

To get an idea of what the 3 images should be like, open your GUI Builder -> Select Theme -> switch to constants tab at the UIID section and you will find the 3 UIID mentioned above there. If they're not, click add and look for them in the dropdown, then add them all.

After finishing designing your switch images, replace the default images. Keep modifying and testing until your OnOffSwitch flow smoothly.

Comment: That is 100% true when the on-off switch is in iOS mode. When its in Android mode it works like a button that gets shifted

Comment: So, how do I control the appearance of the button AND the background in Android?